# Using a variable property value for NSCalendarIdentifier return nil

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to init an NSCalendar with a value that is variable like below:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:jam.calenderType];
```

But `calendar` always returns `nil`

I know that:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic];
```

And:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

both work fine but I want the value to be `jam.calenderType` which is an `NSString` that has the value of `@"NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic"` or `@"NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the way you store the calendar identifier in your variable. When you wrote `@"NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic"` it simply means a string with that characters, and not the string that the `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic` identifier points to.

So simply set your variable `jam.calenderType = NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic;` or `jam.calenderType = NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian;` and it would work fine.

Another easy solution would have been to make your `calenderType` as a `BOOL` or `int` and then based on it's value to chose `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic` or `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian` in your calendar init.

Comment: Thanks. `jam.calenderType = NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic;` simply fixed it.